# My function isn't working can someone help me out

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making this parkour map with my friends on a server so I made a function for the checkpoints but only one of the commands is working, here is the function:

```
playsound minecraft:entity.arrow.hit_player ambient koky_man456 
title @s actionbar {"text":"Checkpoint!","color":"gold"}
```

Only the playsound command is working, the title command isn't working can someone help?

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade! Do you have any error messages related to your checkpoint commands?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to `@p` or `@a`.

```
title @s actionbar {"text":"Checkpoint!","color":"gold"}
      ^^
```

In a command block `@s` is nobody (aka. the command block itself), and therefore won't display to anyone. Try putting it as `@p` or `@a[distance=..10]`.

You'll want to use `@s` if it was `execute as @p title @s actionbar {"text":"Checkpoint!","color":"gold"}`.

---

See [Target Selectors](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Target_selectors) for more information.

Comment: They never said it was a command block. It is a function.

Comment: Only happens if you're using a command block